# Get the name of the layer when I click on it with openlayers 3

Tags: wms, openlayers, layers

I have a question, I need to make more than one GetFeatureInfo (obtaining information under the layer that you click), and for this I need the name of the layer I click on it to get the information.

Anyone know how to get the name of this layer?

This is my getFeatureInfo code:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
          var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);

          var url = WMS2.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
              {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
               'propertyName': 'referencia'});


          if (url) {
            var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
             $.ajax({url: url,

                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response) {

              var result = parser.readFeatures(response);

              if (result.length) {
                var info2 = [];
                for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
                  info2.push(result[i].get('referencia'));
                }
                document.getElementById("Getfeatureinfo").value = info2;

              } else {
                document.getElementById("Getfeatureinfo").value = info2;

              }
            }});
```

Comment: You can send several request to all your wms layer and then get all response.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33021224/5149997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly get the name of the layers. But each layers first column has the layer name.feature_id

Just try to parse the json and get the first column in to into string
then by use string.split function

```
for(var i in result.features){
    var id = result.features[i].id;
    var layer_name = id.split(".")[0];
}
```